# Completely reload style.css

Tags: cache, css, plugin-wp-supercache

I have inherited a site, and I'm trying to add new styles to the style.css

Things I have tried that have NOT worked

- Reload browser cache
- delete WP Super Cache cache
- Disabled WP Super Cache plugin completely
- add !important to my styles
- removed 'Version:' from css comment at the top of style.css
- edited style.css ditrectly from Appearance > Editor rather than push via ftp
- many combinations of all of these

I notice in the web inspector that all styles are coming from style.css:1 (line 1) which makes me thing there is a css minification going on somewhere

Is there an default cache somewhere to clear via GUI?

Is there a css cache file I can delete from the server?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Apparently this is a cache related problem. Are you using third-party services such as Cloudflare or other?

Comment: isn't there an option on **WP Super Cache** to delete cache or reset cache or something?

Comment: @Chun I have deleted all WP Super Cache. As well as completely disabled it.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the cache before deleting the plugin? I'm thinking your browser is still reading the cached files either because the cached version is still on your browser or somehow Wordpress is still displaying the cached version. Try pressing `Ctrl`+`F5` or `Shift`+`F5` to refresh the page ignoring the cached content on your browser.

Comment: @Chun I'm constantly clearing cache from my browser and viewing it in incognito/private mode. I don't think browser is the issue. I think there may be an alternate caching layer on the server or a plugin/setting on the site I cannot navigate to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Network tool in the Inspector I found out that there was a third party caching service in action. "Cloudflare" via Bluehost.